# Powershell PSSession variable context

Tags: powershell

I am using New-PSSession to run a command on a remote machine, via Invoke-Command. As an example, let's say the machine I am running the command FROM is called FROM-MACHINE, and the machine I am running the command TO is called TO-MACHINE.

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName TO-MACHINE
$script = ScriptBlock::Create("Write-Host Machine name is $env:COMPUTERNAME")
Invoke-Command -session $session -scriptBlock $script
```

I would expect this to output:

```
Machine name is TO-MACHINE
```

However, it actually outputs

```
Machine name is FROM-MACHINE
```

This also happens in the case of file paths - if I want to run a program at "C:\myprogram.exe" powershell will attempt to find myprogram.exe at "\\FROM-MACHINE\c$\myprogram.exe".

My question is this: is there any way (other than using psexec) to truly run a remote command, variables and all? Am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are using a double quoted string for your script block creation.  $env:COMPUTERNAME is being expanded to the local computer name before the script block is created.  If you use a single-quoted string, $env:COMPUTERNAME will get passed in the script block as literal text, and expansion won't happen until it gets executed on the remote machine.  So, when you're creating script blocks from strings for execution on remote machines, us expandable (double quoted) strings when you want to use local variables in the script block, and non-expandable (single quoted) strings when you want to use variables from the remote machine.

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName TO-MACHINE
$script = [ScriptBlock]::Create('$env:COMPUTERNAME')
Invoke-Command -session $session -scriptBlock $script
```

If you want to mix and match in the same script block, use an expandable string, and then escape the $ on all the remote variable references with a backtick:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName TO-MACHINE 
$script = [ScriptBlock]::Create(" Write-output $env:Computername; Write-Output `$env:COMPUTERNAME ")
Invoke-Command -session $session -scriptBlock $script
```

Comment: What about the case where I am running a script remotely? Even if the script I'm running is on a different box, it still reports variables in the context of FROM-MACHINE.

Comment: Did you test that second script I posted?  It should return the local machine name first, and then the remote machine name.

Comment: Does that script live on your local machine or the remote machine?  If  it's on the local machine, I'd use Invoke-Command -FilePath .  If it's on the remote machine, then single quote the string, or just pass the script block directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid this situation by declaring your `ScriptBlock` directly in your code as a `ScriptBlock` instead of a `String` object. You do this by simply surrounding the code in curly braces. You can store the `ScriptBlock` object in a variable, and then pass it into `Invoke-Command` just as you were before, with the `-ScriptBlock` parameter.

```
$ScriptBlock = {
    $Program = 'c:\MyProgram.exe';
    Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $Program -ArgumentList 'args go here';

    Write-Host -Object "Write-Host Machine name is $env:COMPUTERNAME";
    }

Invoke-Command -ComputerName to-machine -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock;
```

**Note**: You do not have to manually create PowerShell Remoting sessions. `Invoke-Command` will take care of that for you, unless you specifically want to leave them open in the background.